# Bootstrap - Divs in a row are causing shift/jump effect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page developed using twitter bootstrap version 2. I have a row that is divided into span8 and span4. Span8 has some image slider (built with jquery) and span4 has just some links. When the page loads, all the links in the span 4 is displayed first and then when the image loads, the text gets pushed to right. Is there a way to prevent this shift/jump effect?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8" id="imgDiv">
            <!-- Image slider goes here -->
        </div>
        <div class="span4" id="linksDiv">
            <ul>
               <li>link1</li>
               <li>link2</li>
               <li>link3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what sort of jump/shift. Do you have a link/jsfiddle. Its easier to help when you can see what the problem is

Comment: I will create a jsfiddle and post the link. Because the images load slow, first the text appears on the left and when the images get loaded, the text gets shifted to the right of the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have devised the following solution. Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sJq6y/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8">
        <div class="imgDiv">
            <h1> Image slider goes here </h1> 
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="span4 linksDiv">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Link One</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Link Two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Link Duo</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.linksDiv ul {
    list-style:none;
    background-color:lightgrey;
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    padding:10px;
}

.imgDiv h1 {
    text-align:center;
    color:tomato;
}
```

**Images**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably due to styling coming from #imgDiv and #linksDiv.

Would this option work for you?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span8">
  <div id="imgDiv">
        <!-- Image slider goes here -->  
  </div> <!-- end #imgDiv -->
    </div>
    <div class="span4">  
    <div id="linksDiv">
        <ul>
           <li>link1</li>
           <li>link2</li>
           <li>link3</li>
        </ul>  
    </div> <!-- end #linksDiv -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Good luck!